# Attempting unit test, "You popped a context which you never pushed..."

Tags: apex, unit-test, gack, force-cli

Lately when trying to execute a unit test using the Force cli tool I'm getting an error I've never seen before.

> ERROR: You popped a context which you never pushed, check for unbalanced push and pops: ContextFrame:common.apex.cache.ApexClassEntryHD$Data@746f3b19:Established by /services/Soap/s/34.0/00DP00000002qmM
>   Established at Fri May 13 16:21:24 GMT 2016
>    Error Id: 89500380-45258 (-1565232116)

Anyone recognize where it may be coming from?

Comment: That's an internal server error. Contact support. It shouldn't be possible for this error to surface because the Apex Code runtime should catch it.

Comment: you might try v36 to see if the problem has been subsequently fixed. Good luck. See this [gack page](https://developer.salesforce.com/blogs/engineering/2015/02/gack.html) for background